# Mouse clicked on random image in python

Tags: python, pygame

I am beginner in python. Recently i am doing a pygame poject. I want to make a game where the screen will show an image in a random position, and after 0.3 seconds, the image will move to another random position again. The player will repeatedly click on the position-changed image with the mouse and the score will increase. Even if I do everything, clicking with the mouse does not increase the score.

Here is my code:

```py
pygame.init()
width = 500
height = 500
score = 0
display = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Tapping")
image = pygame.image.load('spaceship.png').convert()
sides = ['Top', 'Botom', 'left', 'Right']
weights = [width, width, height, height]
posx = random.randint(50, 450)
posy = random.randint(20, 460)
tsp = 1.2
Mousex = 0
Mousey = 0

def image_view(x, y):
    display.blit(image, (x, y))

run = True
while run:
    display.fill((153, 255, 187))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            Mousex, Mousey = event.pos
            if image.get_rect().collidepoint(posx, posy):
                score += 1

    side = random.choices(sides, weights)[0]

    if side == 'Top':
        posx = random.randrange(100, 300)
        posy = random.randrange(20, 100)
        time.sleep(tsp)
    elif side == 'Botom':
        posx = random.randrange(350, 430)
        posy = random.randrange(250, 450)
        time.sleep(tsp)
    elif side == 'left':
        posx = random.randrange(20, 250)
        posy = random.randrange(20, 250)
        time.sleep(tsp)
    elif side == 'Right':
        posx = random.randrange(280, 450)
        posy = random.randrange(280, 450)
        time.sleep(tsp)

    print(score)
    image_view(posx, posy)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to evaluate if the mouse is on the image. Note, a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) has no position. It is `blit` at a position. Hence the position of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object, which is returned by [`get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) is (0, 0).
You have to set the position by a keyword argument (e.g. `image.get_rect(topleft = (posx, posy))`). Finally you can use [`collidepoint()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) to evaluate if the mouse cursor (`Mousex`, `Mousey`) is on the region of the display, where the image is currently placed:

```py
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    Mousex, Mousey = event.pos
    image_rect = image.get_rect(topleft = (posx, posy))
    if image_rect.collidepoint(Mousex, Mousey):
        score += 1
```

---

Further more, `time.sleep(tsp)` prevents the system from responding. Never delay the main application loop.
Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to get get the time in milliseconds. Add a variable `next_choice_time`. The time indicates when the position of the image has to be changed. Set a new time when the position of the image is changed:

```py
next_choice_time = 0
while run:
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            Mousex, Mousey = event.pos
            image_rect = image.get_rect(topleft = (posx, posy))
            if image_rect.collidepoint(Mousex, Mousey):
                score += 1
                next_choice_time = current_time

    if current_time >= next_choice_time:
        next_choice_time = current_time + 300 # 300 milliseconds == 0.3 seconds
        side = random.choices(sides, weights)[0]
        # [...]
```

---

See the example:

```py
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
width = 500
height = 500
score = 0
display = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Tapping")
image = pygame.image.load('spaceship.png').convert()
sides = ['Top', 'Botom', 'left', 'Right']
weights = [width, width, height, height]
posx = random.randint(50, 450)
posy = random.randint(20, 460)
tsp = 1.2
Mousex = 0
Mousey = 0

def image_view(x, y):
    display.blit(image, (x, y))

run = True

next_choice_time = 0
while run:
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            Mousex, Mousey = event.pos
            image_rect = image.get_rect(topleft = (posx, posy))
            if image_rect.collidepoint(Mousex, Mousey):
                score += 1
                next_choice_time = current_time
                print(score)

    if current_time >= next_choice_time:
        next_choice_time = current_time + 300 # 300 milliseconds == 0.3 seconds
        side = random.choices(sides, weights)[0]
        if side == 'Top':
            posx = random.randrange(100, 300)
            posy = random.randrange(20, 100)
        elif side == 'Botom':
            posx = random.randrange(350, 430)
            posy = random.randrange(250, 450)
        elif side == 'left':
            posx = random.randrange(20, 250)
            posy = random.randrange(20, 250)
        elif side == 'Right':
            posx = random.randrange(280, 450)
            posy = random.randrange(280, 450)

    display.fill((153, 255, 187))
    image_view(posx, posy)
    pygame.display.update()
```